# How to deal with extreme values messing up Graduated colours? (ArcMap)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, visualisation, color-ramp

Is there an easy way to deal with extreme values messing up the Graduated colours of a map and skew the intervals in such a way that the colour ramp still makes visible sense?

I have a map displaying changes between two sets of numbers - I have chosen a colour ramp that goes from blue to red, each fading to yellow in the middle and want the decreases to be displayed in blue while the increases to be displayed in red, with little to no change being displayed as yellow. Ideally using 7-10 colour bands to display varying magnitudes of increase/decrease.

However, because I am mapping the percentage change, the decreases are capped at -100%, whereas some of the increases are in the many thousands of percent. This leads to an overall skew whereby all decreases and even smaller increases fall into the darkest blue colour section of the colour ramp, and all but the most extreme increases are also displayed as (slightly lighter) blues, thus making it look at a glance like the numbers are almost exclusively decreasing, which is not the case.

When I try to classify the break values manually, the axes of the chart where you can drag the break values are also skewed by the extreme large values which make it difficult to see/change the lower breaks - and using the percentage function on the right, is similarly difficult due to the fact that even tiny percentages give a break value above 0.

Is there a certain classification that is designed for data distributed in such a way? Or something I can do to the results that will make the classification/visualisation easier?